# Find records that contains at least one word of a string

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq

I have the table Doctors

```
Doctors:
------------
ID
FullName
```

The user inserts a string that can contain many words like : "Leon Simmons" and i want to get all the the doctors that has either "Leon" or "Simmons" in their names.
The problem is that i don't know how many words will the user insert. 
How can I do such thing with linq?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
IQueryable<Doctor> doctorQuery = dbContext.Doctors;
foreach(var word in searchWords)
    doctorQuery = doctorQuery.Where(x => x.FullName.ToLower().Contains(word.ToLower());
return await doctorQuery.ToListAsync();
```

Comment: But answer here, does exactly what I needed!

Answer (score 1):

You can use SqlMethods.Like().

An example of the usage:

```
var results =
        from d in doctors
        where SqlMethods.Like(u.FullName, "%Leon Simmons%")
        select d;
```

Comment: This will only help if there is an exact "Leon Simmons" field, it wouldn't work for "Simmons Leon".

Comment: Ideally you would be passing in the name in some kinda of variable, and you should handle validating and sanitizing that before passing it to the lookup call.

Answer (score 1):

One possible solution using linq method syntax:

```
    dbContext.Doctors
     .Where(d => d.FullName.Contains("Leon") || d.FullName.Contains("Simmons"))
     .Count();
```

Comment: How can i use this solution? I don't know haw ,any word I have within the string. i can't trim it like that.